# Blue green deployment on microservices - how to route 10% of traffic to one one instance and remaining 90% of traffic to other instance

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, microservices

I have two instances of the same microservice in Bluemix(cloud Foundry). I want to route 90% of the traffic to one service and remaining 10% of the traffic to other service. Can you tell me how to do this in Bluemix

Answer (score 1):

Actually it isn't supported on Bluemix.
A solution could be install and run a load balancer correctly configured as you need on a container and make it forwarding the requests to your agents following your balancing policy.
If you create a container group instead of a container you could also have a fault tolerant solution without having a single point of failure.

Comment: Can you just provide me a blog link or any other link which explains how to set up a load balancer in  bluemix.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any blog post regarding that, but you could follow any post regarding a service configuration on a docker container. About the software balancer I suggest you to use haproxy or varnish: this last one is a webproxy but could be easily configured as a load balancer and have a very easy 'configuration' language. You could also start for an already available docker image, you can search on Google or, better, you could search on https://hub.docker.com/ .  About containers you should start from Bluemix official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in Cloud Foundry, the open-source platform Bluemix is based upon.

The only work-around is to have nine instances of the old service and one of the new. The round-robin load-balancer will on average then distribute 10% of traffic to the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

As James said - it's not possible currently.

One workaround you could use to "simulate" a load balancer would be to set up an application which fronts all of the requests. Bind the route to this application and then include some logic inside it which just redirects traffic to the other services in a 9:1 ratio.

The risks of using this approach are:

- Your load-balancer application could theoretically go down
- Your load-balancer application doesn't know the status of the other two services so might route traffic to an offline service instance

You can minimize the first risk by using multiple instances on the "load balancer" app.